# Can someone help me with the intuition behind this combinatorics problem from Blitzstein's Stats 110?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Premise: "A jar contains r red balls and g green balls, where r and g are fixed positive integers. A ball is drawn from the jar randomly (with all probabilities equally likely), and then a second ball is drawn randomly"

Question: "Suppose that there are 16 balls in total, and that the probability that the two balls are the same color is the same as the probability that they are different colors. What are r and g?"

I understand that the only way the two probabilities equal each other are if they're both 1/2 - that's obvious. I also understand that the denominator in terms of how many combinations that can be selected is (g+r)*(g+r-1). But I don't understand why in the solutions, they state the numerator as 2gr. I understand the algebra after setting (2gr)/((g+r)*(g+r-1)) equal to 1/2 and solving the quadratic equation. I just don't get the intuition of why the numerator is 2gr in the first place.

Comment: We want the probability of picking two balls of different colours. There are $r$ red and $g$ green, so the total number of pairs of is $rg$. The factor of $2$ is to account for the fact that we could pick red first then green, or green first then red.

Comment: I guess my question then is, why in the denominator do we take into account "decrementing by 1 ball already being chosen" (g+r)*(g+r-1) and in the numerator we dont?

Comment: Let's say I pick a green ball first. There are $g$ choices for the green ball. After I've picked a green ball, there are still $r$ choices for the red ball. Same logic applies when I pick a red ball first.

Comment: Ah got it got it. Interesting. Thank you!